# Find frequency from the Fourier series?

Tags: physics, fourier-series

I have the Fourier series. What I want to do is find the first 3 terms and then find the bandwidth

Here is what the first 3 terms are:

$\sin(2πf_1t+\frac{π}{2}) + \frac{1}{9}sin(6πf_1t+\frac{π}{2}) + \frac{1}{25}sin(10πf_1t+\frac{π}{2}) $

Now Im not sure how I can find the lowest and the highest frequency from this answer? Could anyone give me some hints?
Thank you

Comment: It looks like you have a shifted Fourier series $g(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2\, n-1)^2}\, \sin\left(2\, \pi\, (2\,n-1)\, f_1\, t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. The lowest frequency is the frequency of the first term $\sin\left(2\, \pi\, f_1\, t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which is $f_1$. The highest frequency of the first three terms is the frequency of the third term $\frac{1}{25}\, \sin\left(2\, \pi\, 5\, f_1\, t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ which is $5\, f_1$.